# How to display items from API

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have success to display the items with ListView.builder, now I want to display the items based on their ACTIVE or INACTIVE status at API. So when I want to display ACTIVE, it only shows the active items, and goes the same with INACTIVE.

And my code is like this:

```
BlocBuilder<FoodBloc, FoodState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: state.food.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Row(
                            children: [
                              const SizedBox(
                                height: 10,
                                width: 10,
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  foregroundColor:
                                      ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(
                                width: 5,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                state.food[index].identity,
                                style: subtitle1(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this without having to create an extra counter for active devices:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: state.food.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: state.food[index].status == "ACTIVE" ? true : false,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
            width: 10,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              foregroundColor: ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
              backgroundColor: ColorName.brandSecondaryGreen,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            state.food[index].identity,
            style: subtitle1(),
          ),
        ),
    ],
  );
```